# How to fix the problem deleting an item from mongodb in react?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb

I am trying to delete an item from mongodb but failed.

Here is the server side code:

```
// to delete single data
  app.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log(id);
    tasksCollection
      .deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) })
      .then((result) => {
        res.send(result.deletedCount > 0);
        console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

here is the client side code:

```
function deleteProduct(id) {
    console.log(id);
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/delete/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      });
  }
```

and the errors showing from server site:

```
ReferenceError: id is not defined
```

and the error showing from client site:

```
DELETE http://localhost:5000/delete/5f780abe7ce75b5be88ebd44 500 (Internal Server Error)
localhost/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

and here is my click handler:

```
<div>
      <h3>This is home</h3>
      {showTasks.map((showTask) => (
        <div>
          <h4>{showTask.name}</h4>
          <button onClick={() => deleteProduct(`${showTask._id}`)}>
            Delete tasks
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
```

at client site code I have console.log(id). if I click delete task button, I can get the specific id of the task, but the problem is in the fetch. and so id is not defined in server site code. anyone please help me how can I fix that???

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your `console.log(id)`, it should be `console.log(req.params.id)`. Since id is not defined there, it gives you the error : `ReferenceError: id is not defined`

Try this:

```
// to delete single data
  app.delete("/delete/:id", (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id); //req.params.id instead of id
    tasksCollection
      .deleteOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) })
      .then((result) => {
        res.send(result.deletedCount > 0);
        console.log(result);
      });
  });
```

Also, the error that you are getting in the client-side is because of `res.json()` The response you are getting is not a stringified json, so you might not do that, and just try to print `res`

Comment: The problem still exists and that is internal server error status code: 500. and the server side error now is "ObjectId is not defined".